# Do the same parameters of different JNI calls have the same values?

Tags: java, interface, java-native-interface, native

For example, there are two different JNI methods of the SAME object

```
class JavaObj{
   public native void methodA();
   public native void methodB();
}
```

The JNI headers for these methods could be

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JavaObj_methodA(JNIEnv * pEnv, jobject javaobj);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JavaObj_methodB(JNIEnv * pEnv, jobject javaobj);
```

So is it safe to assume that the values of pEnv and javaobj are the SAME in these two seperate JNI calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. The JNIEnv * can change any time between JNI calls, and you can have multiple instances of your class.